# Inner working of Bidirectional RNNs

Tags: deep-learning, recurrent-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory, time-series, gated-recurrent-unit

I'm trying to understand how Bidirectional RNNs work.

Specifically, I want to know whether a single cell is used with  different states, or two different cells are used, each having independent parameters.

In pythonic pseudocode,

Implementation 1:

```
cell = rev_cell = RNNCell()
cell_state = cell.get_initial_state()
rev_cell_state = rev_cell.get_initial_state()
for i in range(len(series)):
    output, cell_state = cell(series[i], cell_state)
    rev_output, rev_cell_state = rev_cell(series[-i-1], rev_cell_state)
    final_output = concatenate([output, rev_output])
```

Implementation 2:

```
cell = RNNCell()
rev_cell = RNNCell()
cell_state = cell.get_initial_state()
rev_cell_state = rev_cell.get_initial_state()
for i in range(len(series)):
    output, cell_state = cell(series[i], cell_state)
    rev_output, rev_cell_state = rev_cell(series[-i-1], rev_cell_state)
    final_output = concatenate([output, rev_output])
```

Which of the above implementations is correct? Or is the working of Bidirectional RNNs completely different altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second implementation looks more correct and inline with how Bidirectional is defined. Specifically, bidirectionality doen't change the forward/backward logic of either direction, and just merges (concat/sum/...) the outputs of forward/backward at a matching timestep `t`.

You can check how Keras implements it [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/layers/wrappers.py#L388). There are distinct `self.forward_layer` and `self.backward_layer` that are initialized separately.

Your `for` loop doesn't look ok though. To calculate the output at time step `0` you'd have to calculate `forward(0)` and `backward(n)`, which means you have to run backward on all the samples first. In practice, each direction is calculated separately and the results are merged afterwards. Check the implementaion in Keras [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/layers/wrappers.py#L529).